# Apart from the Padma Purana, does any other Purana say that Adi Shankaracharya will teach mayavadi philosophy?

Tags: scripture, shiva, advaita, adi-shankaracharya, padma-purana

In the Padma Purana, Uttara Khanda, Chapter 236, Lord Shiva says to Parvati that He would incarnate as Adi Shankaracharya to teach the mayavadi philosophy:

> *mayavadam asac chastram pracchannam bauddham uchyate
>   mayaiva kalpitam devi kalau brahmana rupina* (Padma Purana 6.236.7)
>
> **Translation**: "Mayavada or Advaita philosophy is an impious, wicked belief and against all the conclusions of the Vedas. It is only covered Buddhism. My dear Parvati, in Kali-Yoga I assume the form of a brahmana (Adi Shankara) and teach this imagined philosophy.
>
> *apartham sruti-vakyanam darsayan loka-garhitam
>   sva-karma-rupam tyajya tvam atraiva pratipadyate
>   sarva-karma paribhrastair vaidharma tvam tad ucyate
>   paresa-jiva-paraikyam maya tu pratipadyate* (Padma Purana 6.236.8-9)
>
> **Translation**: "This mayavada advaita philosophy preached by me (in form of Adi Shankara) deprives the words of the holy texts of their acutal meaning and thus it is condemned in the world. It recommends the renunciation of one's own duties, since those who have fallen from their duties say that the giving up of duties is religiosity. In this way, I have also falsely propounded the identity of the Supreme Lord and the individual soul."
>
> *brahmanas caparam rupam nirgunam vaksyate maya
>   sarva-svam jagato py asya mohanartham kalu yuge* (Padma Purana 6.236.10)
>
> **Translation**: "In order to bewilder the atheists, in Kali-yuga, I describe the Supreme Personality of Godhead Lord Krishna to be without any form and without qualities."
>
> *vedante tu maha-sastrera mayavadam avaidikam
>   mayaiva vaksyate devi jagatam nasha-karanat* (Padma Purana 6.236.11)
>
> **Translation**: "Similarly, in explaining Vedanta scripture, I described the same non-scriptural and inauspicious mayavada philosophy in order to mislead the entire population toward atheism by denying the personal form of my beloved Lord."

Are there any similar verses in other scriptures saying that Lord Shiva would appear as a Brahmana to preach the mayavada philosophy?

Comment: @TheDestroyer is Śaṅkara's history in some scriptures. How can we rely on any scripture.

Comment: @AnuragSingh See [Are there any other Puranas that predict Adi Shanakaracharya besides the Bhavishya Purana?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14738/3500)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following verses are from Garuda Purana, Brahma kanda, 16th Adyaya:

> maNimAnnAma daityastu shaN^karAkhyo bhaviShyati |
>
> sarveShAM saN^karaM yastu kariShyati na saMshayaH || 3:16:70
>
> tena shaN^karanAmA.asau bhaviShyati khageshvara |
>
> dharmAn.h bhAgavatAn.h sarvAn.h vinashyati sarvathA || 3:16:71

A Demon by name maNimAn will come into being as Shankara, who will, no doubt, pollute everything. This is why, O King of birds (Garuda), his name will be Shankara; he will pollute and destroy all BhAgavata Dharmas.

[Source](https://www.indiadivine.org/content/topic/1290221-was-adi-sankara-a-demon/)

> vAyu purANa :-
>
> janayiShyathi Kala: kaScinmaNimAn vidhDhipaarvathi |
>
> praviSya thathra dhEvESa pracCannam boudhDhamEvahi ||
>
> ( Rudradeva saying to ParvathiDevi-When Demon by name Maniman will
>   take birth on earth in Kaliyuga, By entering in him, I will preach
>   Advaith Shasthra which is another form of Boudha Shsthra).

**skamdha purANa** :-

> kAladi grAmake rudhrAvESAjjayathi mOhayan |
>
> boudhDhaSAsthra parO viprO ya:kaSciththasya SiShyaka: ||
>
> sasamkaraSca sanyasya thasmAthsanyAsarUpiNa : ||
>
> vEdhAmthaSAsthramithyEthath dhuShtaSAsthram cakArayath ||
>
> ( In a Village which will be called as **Kaaladi**, Demon will take
>   birth with Rudravesha and will be a Disciple of follower of Boudha
>   Shastra and in disguise of a **Sanyasi** (Yathi) will preach
>   **Bouddha** Dharma (Dushta Shasthra) by **misleadingly** saying that he will teach **Vedanta** Shasthra.

[Source](https://xa.yimg.com/kq/groups/E5oU4w3uedWIvaEL5A--/xB7NlEjtf9dKIH.uhrPk/name/For_the_Answer_to_the_Question.pdf)

**Note**: Whether these puranas/verses are genuine or added later is another matter.

> Bhaskara (9th Century CE), the propounder of bhedabheda-siddhanta was
>   one of the earliest Indian philosophers to attack Mayavada. In his
>   commentary on Vedanta-sutra, Bhaskara does not mention Sankara by
>   name, nor does he mention the name of his philosophy. However by
>   reviewing his arguments against the monistic doctrine of maya and the
>   Advaitic concept of anirvacaniya, it is obvious who and what he is
>   alluding to.
>
> Bhaskara is positively vitriolic when writing about the Advaitin’s
>   concept of maya, referring to it’s adherents as bauddha-matavalambin
>   (those that cling to Buddhist ideology) and goes on to say that their
>   philosophy reeks of Buddhism (bauddha-gandhin). Bhaskara concludes
>   that, “No one but a drunkard could hold such theories” and that
>   Mayavada is subversive of all sastrika knowledge:
>
> vigitam vicchinna-mulam mahayanika-bauddhagathitam mayavadam
>   vyavarnayanto lokan vyamohayanti
>
> Expanding on the contradictory and baseless philosophy of maya
>   propagated by the Mahayanika Buddhists, the Mayavadis have misled the
>   whole world. (Bhaskara’s Brahma-sutra-bhasya 1.4.25)
>
> In his Siddha-traya, the Vaisnava philosopher Yamunacarya (917–1042
>   CE) stated that Buddhism and Mayavada was essentially the same thing.
>   The only difference he could see was that while one was openly
>   Buddhist (prakata-saugata), the other was simply covered
>   (pracchana-saugata).
>
> Following on from Yamunacarya, his disciple Sri Ramanuja (1017-1137
>   CE) also concurred that Mayavada was another form of Buddhism. In his
>   Sri Bhashya commentary on the Vedanta-sutras, Ramanuja says that to
>   claim that non-differentiated consciousness is real and all else is
>   false is the same as the Buddhist concept of universal void.
>   Furthermore, Ramanuja states that the concepts of such
>   crypto-Buddhists make a mockery of the teachings of the Vedas
>   (veda-vadacchadma pracchana-bauddha).
>
> Another acarya in the line of Ramanuja, Vedanta Desika (1269–1370)
>   wrote his famous Sata-dusini, a text expounding one hundred flaws
>   found in Mayavada. In that work he refers to Sankara as a
>   rahu-mimamsaka (one who obscures the true meaning of Vedanta), a
>   bhrama-bhiksu (a confused beggar), a cadmavesa-dhari – one who is
>   disguised in false garb, and goes on to assert that, “By memorizing
>   the arguments of the Sata-dusini like a parrot, one would be
>   victorious over the crypto-Buddhists.”
>
> In another work, Paramata-bhangam, Vedanta Desika refers to Sankara
>   as, “One who studied the Vedas in the shop of a Madhyamika Buddhist”
>   (referring to Sankara’s param-guru Gaudapada of whom we will speak of
>   later in this article).

[Source](http://gosai.com/writings/mayavada-and-buddhism-are-they-one-and-the-same)

Comment: So Adi Shankara polluted everything? And who will purify all again? :P **This is why, O King of birds (Garuda), his name will be Shankara** Means what? Shankara from Sham - who gives peace.

Comment: @Rickross now you have problem with puranas too... first decide if you accept these scriptures or not?

Comment: I don't have any problems, you have you don't consider them as scriptures ..but u still quote from them when what they say suits ur agenda..BTW who will purify? Anything mentioned? :P

Comment: @Rickross many people have worked to purify it to an extent, All the post sankara schools have done it. What else am I doing it here?

Comment: OH i see so u are also one of those who will purify? :P But no scriptures mention u as the purifying agent..

Comment: @Rickross where did i mention that its mentioned in scripture? No scripture mentioned Ramakrishna paramahansa deva and aurobindo and anandamayi mata also right? yet they did right?? yes?

Comment: Wow! Puranas even saying names. Haha. very good. What were those people who read these Puranas before doing when Shankara was roaming entire India.

Comment: @TheDestroyer you dont know that puranas mention names? then what have you observed in puranas till now ?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Please mention exact locations of Vayu purana and Skanda Purana verses.

Comment: @TheDestroyer i have only this info.

Comment: @TheDestroyer out of these three mentions, only Garuda purana is given with some numbers. I tried searching in Garuda purana but it is no where to be found. Please if you find the exact location of purana, paste it here. I am hereby forced to conclude, as of now, as this to be a concocted unauthentic verses using Hitchens Razor https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitchens%27s_razor

Comment: And in the place of second source, I saw this, that instead it is predicted that Vayu will incarnate as maniman. https://ia600207.us.archive.org/BookReader/BookReaderImages.php?zip=/19/items/GarudaPuranaEnglishMotilal3VolumesIn1/Garuda%20Purana%20English%20-%20Motilal%20-%203%20Volumes%20in%201_jp2.zip&file=Garuda%20Purana%20English%20-%20Motilal%20-%203%20Volumes%20in%201_jp2/Garuda%20Purana%20English%20-%20Motilal%20-%203%20Volumes%20in%201_1057.jp2&scale=4&rotate=0

Comment: No its there in garuda purANa

Comment: Without Sri  Adi Sankaracharya, the Sanatana dharma would not havev survived. Here He is being criticised as demon! I a so fortunate I have avoided reading most of these puranas.

Comment: @ParthaBanerjee that is why i said you that most of Vedantins have condemned and criticized each other to prove themselves right

Comment: @ParthaBanerjee Caitanya and his pupils also were very critical about sankara vedanta.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi They had to form aparticular sect. but puran's duty is not that

Comment: @ParthaBanerjee no for forming sect you dont have to show others in a bad light.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi they did not make ANY personal attack like calling demon.They only ctiticised His philosophy

Comment: @ParthaBanerjee https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17249/7853

Comment: @ChakrapaniNRao You won't find it. It might be present in other manuscripts.

Comment: I lost all but 10 brain cells after reading the question, rest all the brain cells got lost after reading the answer.

Comment: Brahma khanda of the Garuda purana itself is a later interpolation by madhvas as it's not present in most of the manuscripts. Moreover vaishnavas themselves hold that Sharkaracharya held vishnusarvottamatva so saying he destroyed bhagavata dharmas contradicts the vaishnavite position itself