# Any work of Madhwacharya or his disciples says Ramanuja was a demon?

Tags: ramanujacharya, madhvacharya

[Ramanujacharya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanuja) was a saint who propagated Vishishtadvaita Vedanta philosophy by writing commentaries on Prastanatrayi. Before him, Shankara preached Advaita Vedanta and after him Madhwacharya propagated Dvaita Vedanta in the same manner. It is well known that Madhwa and his followers accused [Shankara as an incarnation of a demon](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28629/do-followers-of-dvaita-really-believe-that-advaitins-are-deceitful-demons) named Maniman using some scriptures like Garuda Purana, Vayu Purana, etc. Now I came across a strange claim that Madhwa's followers even accused Ramanuja as a demon. A member from a [discussion forum](http://www.ibiblio.org/sripedia/ramanuja/archives/apr05/msg00016.html) says the following:

> The knowledge imparted by Sri Ramanuja Acharya is uncontaminated, free from maligned motivations and supremely correct. The authority of his perfection of bhakti is shining in the form of his magnum opus, srI bhAshya, though all his other works are also equally great. He taught the world how to self surrender unto the Supreme Lord as inscribed in the scriptures. In spite of all his glory, **the followers of Sri Ananda Teertha blaspheme** such blemish less **Sri Ramanuja** with harsh words. **Their Acharya even present Sri rAmAnuja as an incarnation of a demon named Vatapi.**

My question is, which work of Madhwacharya or his followers/disciples or anybody from his Guru Parampara says this?

Comment: Users are requested not to comment on authenticity of passage or on Ramanuja or Madhwa here. Just answer the question below if anyone knows answer.

Comment: From the [same website, on the same thread](http://www.ibiblio.org/sripedia/ramanuja/archives/apr05/msg00038.html)

Comment: @SudarshanaSuri above mentioned link doesn't say anything about which scripture mention this or I couldn't able to find it.

Comment: I explain my above comment as requested by OP: The question *may* lead to the source website being construed unintentionally as though it is one-sided, this is bad in general in my understanding - since the link in my comment expresses similar concerns as expressed in this question, I felt it was responsible to just point out to everyone to know: that this website is conscientious and is not unreasonable in its discussions.

Comment: In short, [this link](http://www.ibiblio.org/sripedia/ramanuja/archives/apr05/msg00016.html) in the question is not a post by a website but a post by some user in a forum discussion on the website and it received [this linked response](http://www.ibiblio.org/sripedia/ramanuja/archives/apr05/msg00038.html) mentioned in my comment by other members in the same forum expressing the concerns you happen to voice in this question.

Answer (score 9):

A work in Kannada 'Harikathamrutasara' by Jagannatha dasa opens with the declaration that 21 duratmas wrote kubhashyas on Brahmasutra and Madhva came to refute them. A commentary on the work lists the 21 and Ramanuja is one. Thus for Madhwas Ramanuja is a duraatma and his Sribhashya is kubhashya. The Sumadhwa vijaya too talks of kubhashya and the author himself lists the 21 in his own commentary. For Madhwa and his followers everyone excepting Madhwa is a demon.