# Position of statements by unprophesied famous/great people of kaliyuga in the hierarchy of authority in sanathan dharma

Tags: scripture, kali-yuga

> In case of any differences, the well known *hierarchy of scriptures* ([according to scriptures](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20667/661)) are
>
> 1) Veda
>
> 2) Smriti and
>
> 3) Puranas

There are a lot of [great persons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hindu_gurus_and_sants) in Sanathan dharma, belongs to Kali Yuga, who are gurus, saints, acharyas, rishis, yogis, pandits, poets etc.,

Some of those were already prophesied by scriptures. Example: [Adi Shankaracharya](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14738/are-there-any-other-puranas-that-predict-adi-shanakaracharya-besides-the-bhavish). (Say category I)

Many of them were considered great, but does not have any explicit mention in any of the scripture. This question is about these sort of people. (Say category II)

If there is any differences between the statements of those people (of category II) and the scriptures(mentioned in the hierarchy above), then which one has to be considered i.e, what is the position of those people in the hierarchy of authority according to the scriptures, which are top in the hierarchy?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Can you please edit to clarify?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Is it clear now?

Comment: the question of trust is a never-ending loop. suppose i say an answer X. then you can again ask 'why should I trust X, or which scripture says should i trust @ram's opinion' ? Whatever answer someone gives, you can ask 'why trust that' ? The best answer is already given by Manu - "I have dealt with 1000 different situations, but if there are any left out, ask the senior-most women folk in your family and follow them". in other words, follow your elders.

Comment: if u ask "what if elders are wrong", again it's never ending loop. But there is a simple way to break out of this loop. Bhagavan has created world in such a way that even if u follow 1 dharma properly, it will lead to other dharmas automatically. it's like rivers.. no matter which mountain they generate from and which path they take, they all end up in sea.

Comment: @ram Is the question narrowed down now? The question assumes trust on the scriptures  which are top in the hierarchy.

Comment: i think the answer is obvious - follow YOUR guru. that's what all the 'main' acharyas did. they followed THEIR guru. They didn't question who was the BEST guru. Everyone has a guru. If no guru, then parents are guru. The acharyas followed THEIR guru, until bhagavan through their own manas-sakshi urged them to blaze their own path (which was also accepted by scriptures)

Comment: You mean something like Rishis > Acharyas > Saints.... ?

Comment: @ram Are you saying that category II people are top in the hierarchy incase of difference?

Comment: @Pandya No, I want answer something like Vedas -> Smritis ->  puranas -> category II ....

Comment: @hanugm Visit [this one](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20664/277) where Work of Acharyas are mentioned in last. I think this is similar question looking for hierarchy?

Comment: @Pandya Yeah similar question. If any statement from the scriptures saying that the people (gurus, acharyas, saints, yogis etc.,) should be considered after scriptures only or otherwise can be an answer.