# Scriptual references for Adi Shankaracharya and Chhatrapati Shivaji Maharaj being Lord Shiva's avatars

Tags: shiva, avatars, adi-shankaracharya

I have read about Adi Shankaracharya being incarnation of Lord Shiva, similarly in many articles, Chhatrapati Shivaji Maharaj is shown as a
Avatar of Lord Shiva. I want to know about the scriptural references about the same.

Comment: [Are there any other Puranas that predict Adi Shanakaracharya besides the Bhavishya Purana?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14738/3500). This partially answers your question

Answer (score 1):

Did not find any about Chatrapati Shivaji Maraj but I do have a lot of references of Adi Shankaracharya being Shivavtaar.

The Kurma Puran Purva Bhag Chapter 30 verses 33-34 states clearly that in the Kali-yuga, lord Rudra (known as Nila-Lohita) will incarnate on earth in order to reestablish the principles and doctrines of the Shrutis and Smritis in order to bring welfare for all his devotees and if we observe the deeds and preachings of Adi Shankaracharya, it is he who did this work. In the Linga Puran Purva Bhag Chapter 40 verses 19-25 it has been stated that in Kali-yuga, even Bramhans become critics of the Vedas and other scriptures in order to carry forward their own agenda, in such time, lord Rudra (Nila-Lohita) incarnates as Shankara in order to reestablish the doctrines of the Vedas and other scriptures. The same above Adi Shankaracharya which has been stated in the Purans have been stated in the Shaktisangam Tantra Chinnamasta Khand as well.